# Why does gcc give me this result?

Tags: c, gcc

When I run this code gcc gives me the output 10.

Can someone explain to me why it gives me 10? :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int x) {
    int y;
    y = 2*x;
}

int g() {
    int z;
    return z;
}

int main() {
    int x=5;
    f(x);
    printf("%d\n",g());
}
```

Comment: You should never compile your C programs without -Wall, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
int g() {
    int z;
    return z;
}
```

This reads:

```
int g():
    reserve memory for an integer, call it z.
    return whatever is in that reserved memory.
```

You never used that reserved memory for your integer. Its value is whatever was at that address before you chose to use it (or not use it, rather). That value could be anything.

You do the same in your other function. What you are doing is reading uninitialized memory. You can google that up for further information. See also the "stack" and the "heap", dynamic memory, and other related topics.

Answer (score 6):

this is undefined behavior - you are referencing a variable which has no value set to it. likely, it gives 10 because the compiler has used the same memory location for the variable in f(), but there is no guarantee of that, it should not be depended on, and is nothing more than a curiosity.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing to explain. Your code exhibits undefined behaviour on two separate, unrelated occasions: First `f` isn't returning anything despite being declared as returning `int`, and second because `g` returns an uninitialized value.

Practically, the way the functions will be put on the call stack will have caused the local `y` (which eventually has the value `10`) to be in the same place as the return value of `g()` in the `printf` call, so you happen to see the value `10`. But that's more or less a matter of luck.

Comment: Strictly speaking `f()` doesn't have undefined behavior, since the function's value isn't used. However, clearly it's a problem area.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I had this vague idea that "not returning a value from a non-void function" is already UB, not just using that function return value later on. I'd have to check, though. And C may differ from C++ in that regard, too.

Answer (score 0):

g returns an unitialized varable from the stack, in your example that location was last set by the F function giving you your answer of x*2 = 10

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not initializing z, and it's using the same location on the stack as y. Since you're not initializing it the old value is still there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example of why people fear optimizations and when they brag about finding compiler bugs to their bosses. This code as others have alluded to will throw warnings about using uninitialized variables in `g()`. With your compiler settings, it is using the old value on the stack from the call to `f(5)`. With different compiler optimization settings, it will likely have effects on how variables end up on the stack and you'll end up getting a different results when you make changes which appear unrelated. This is undefined behavior and there is no guarantees on what value will result however it is usually easy to explain by understanding the call order and how the compiler sets up the stack. If there are warnings when you're troubleshooting weird behavior like this, fix the warnings first then start asking questions about why.